# Qual web service python usar em uma aplicação usando knockoutjs?

Tags: django, knockoutjs, django-rest-framework

Preciso criar um web service em python para minha aplicação Django. Minha aplicação foi construída usando django e knockoutjs, porém não  uso models nem forms, uso os ko.observable do knockout. Pensei em usar django Rest_Framework, só que ele usa os models do django, alguém me sugere como fazer?

Obrigada.

Comment: Seja bem-vinda ao SO! O que o seu web service precisa prover para sua aplicação em Knockoutjs? Se a sua aplicação não precisar que nenhuma informação venha do Django, você pode servir a página da aplicação como uma página como apenas mais uma view do Django. Você pode esclarecer melhor qual a relação da sua app com o Django?